# Cannot create large sparse files

Tags: high-sierra, filesystem, apfs

I'm using APFS to create mostly empty files.  They get filled progressively later, but first I want to create them with a logical maximum size (and a null physical size).

My problem is that there's a mysterious behaviour that results in MacOS refusing to create too large sparse file, with some threshold that seems to be related to the available space on the device.  But later you can grow that file way beyond the size it first refused.  As a matter of fact if your increments are not too big, you can keep on enlarging your file:

```
$ df -h .
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1  466Gi  425Gi   35Gi    93% 3180883 9223372036851594924    0%   /

$ rm -f big && dd if=/dev/zero of=big bs=1 count=0 seek=$((1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000))
dd: truncating big: No space left on device

$ for i in $(seq 100)
dd if=/dev/zero of=big bs=1 count=0 seek=$((i * 100 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000)) 2>/dev/null
$ ls -lsh big
0 -rw-r--r--  1 akim  wheel   9,1T 17 jan 11:15 big
```

Does it ring any bell?  I venture I should file a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Yeah I have the same result. It doesn't look correct. Any update?

Comment: Nope, it is still present in 10.13.5. I have reported it to Apple, but had no answers.  FWIW, there were other severe bugs in APFS's support for sparse files in 10.13.4 that lead Docker for Mac to disable support for sparse file, but they have been fixed in 10.13.5.  I dunno why this one was not addressed at the same time.

Comment: Can you link to your query to Apple?

Comment: Not very interesting (https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=36617418): it just states "duplicate of 29183238", which I can't read.